# Playlist (embedded ) broken on iOS

Tags: ios, html, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

Since Oct 17th (2013)
Embedded Playlist no longer work on iOS (iPad, iPhone)

Verified on iPad2 (iOS6) , iPhone4s (iOS7)
Verifed with a few different playlists.
Verified by many others

I repeat this is about the STANDARD EMBEDDED PLAYLIST
as it is shown on Youtube-website below the videos (share >embed)
(ie: NOT any special API-script , NOT any "comma-separated-list"
NOT cuePlaylist, NOT SWFobj ..but the SIMPLE STANDARD PLAYLIST EMBED CODE)
as it is shown on Youtube´s website below all videos that are part of a playlist.

They simply don't load and nothing appears just a plain black screen.

When I embed ONLY ONE SINGLE video then it will play fine on iOS

Below (standard) playlist embed-code shows only a black screen and on top
just the title bar with title of the 1st video.

```
<iframe width="928" height="522" src="http//www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLB4CF45A350C9CD8A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Below (extended) code shows only a totally black screen:

```
<iframe width="928" height="522" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLB4CF45A350C9CD8A&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0 "frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As said both codes used to work fine on iOS untill last week 17th.
Both codes work fine on all desktop browsers.

Link to the general youtube help forum
where we are told to post here and
where you can see that others have the same problem:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/playing-and-watching-videos/report-a-technical-issue/ios/_crm-T7BFvM%5B1-25-true%5D

Question-1:

Is this a new bug on Youtube's side ?

Question-2:

Is there a workaround available until they repair it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported issue. Workarounds are here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5411

You can also track the fix from there.

Comment: Its not the same issue ... since this is about the standard embed-code for playlists ...as it is shown on Youtube-website below any video-playlist (share > embed) ..ie: no additional scripts are used ..no "quePlaylist" is used...its the normal standard embed-code ...and it still works fine on normal desktop browsers ..just not on iOS (iPhone,iPad) ...in your link i dont see iOS mentioned neither...this is not about the "comma-separated playlist" neither its not the same issue...its the plain old standard playlist.

Comment: @ Ibrahim...still i checked all the "workarounds" mentioned, but none is working and they are not based on the standard embed-code anyway, its a different issue..unless you can show me a link that shows me that its the same issue ..or shows me a workaround ?

Comment: There were few issues found around that problem, they are filed, will update once the fix is on production.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLmlOlokCCWI8eOeameRUzyqcTXIxzwlKo

This is the way I always use it

Comment: @ ceasar ..that is not a complete embed-code its a plain link, and it opens in a new screen..-and it dont work in ie9 and dont work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to an issue I originally reported on the Google gdata-issues forum.

As of today, Google has fixed it:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5411#c14