# iOS Youtube Embedded video playlists

Tags: ios, ios6, uiwebview, youtube

I'm having an issue embedding youtube videos into my iOS 6.0+ app in a UIWebView. Some of my playlist URLs work while others don't. The ones that don't work simply show a black box in the UIWebView with the appropriate title..but I can't hit play in the UIWebView to start the video.

Example of one that works:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLaLpP50ifUEi3z0IXMuc5EbxChfjj0YCX

Doesn't work:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLaLpP50ifUEhBzltdYTk63BNyVXx53bvj

However, both load properly in a browser.

My embedded NSString is

```
    NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                          <html><head>\
                          <style type=\"text/css\">\
                          body {\
                          background-color: transparent;\
                          color: blue;\
                          }\
                          </style>\
                          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <iframe height=\"200\" width=\"300\" src=\"%@\"></iframe>\
                          </body></html>", url];
```

which I populate with the URL using:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:self.embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Why does this work for some playlist videos and not others?

Thanks!

Comment: The examples that you provided both work in my web browser. Maybe you could take a picture of a working UIWebview and a UIWebview that isn't working and post them in your question. But, as a guess, I think it's because some videos from youtube are not allowed to be embedded per the uploader's request. Which parameters are you including in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not shure if its exactly the same issue
but since last week no playlist will work on iOS (iPhone,iPad)
(embedded on a normal webpage)
occurs with both iOS6 and iOS7.

see my post:

[Playlist (embedded ) broken on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598249/playlist-embedded-broken-on-ios)

They still work in all desktop-browsers.

Single videos will work...maybe that is why your 1st example
still works cause its not a real playlist (?)...since it has only one video in it.

Its a bug @ youtube ... their only reply till now (@google api groups) was
"its filed"   which ofcourse is nothing ...they could just as well have said
"its not filed"  since "filed" means nothing ..they should for a start confirm
that this is a bug ...next they should mention if and when its going to be solved.

Not shure but you may want to add/change a tag ( youtube-api ) not just "youtube" to your first post (if you still can).

## youtube-api

youtube-api